# Pandas apply - Re-using apply result to save time

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to make a new column on a subset of my data-frame that is relatively small (~600 rows) using the apply function and it works but it is slow because the apply function is computationally intensive and I cannot make this black-box function faster / less complex.

However, a lot of the results returned by this black-box function are actually the same (close to 90%) because the inputs are the same. Therefore, is there a way to simply re-use the returned value if the given input is the same to save time?

Here is the code that works but is slow:

```
df.loc[df['number']>=10, 'value'].apply(lambda x: black_box(x).get())
```

Again, most values in the column `value` are identical, resulting in the same output.

Comment: Yes, think you can create a dictionary of the unique values as keys and result of back_box as values, then use map in your datafame to create the new column from the dictionary.

Comment: @ScottBoston Sounds like a great idea, would love to see an example of this if you can provide one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVCE example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key':np.random.randint(1,10,60000),'result':np.nan})

def factorial(x): #Black box
    accum = 1
    for i in range(1,x+1):
        accum *= i
    return accum

%timeit df['result'] = df.key.apply(lambda x: factorial(x))
```

*10 loops, best of 3: 120 ms per loop*

Create dictionary of unique values using black box:

```
def fact_d(values):
    d = {}
    for i in values:
        d[i] = factorial(i)
    return d

dict = fact_d((df.key.unique().tolist()))
```

Map dictionary to dataframe:

```
%timeit df['result'] = df.key.map(dict)
```

*100 loops, best of 3: 6.22 ms per loop*

Answer (score 1):

Scott's suggestion is good, another option would be to use `GroupBy.transform`:

```
s = df.loc[df['number'] >= 10, 'value']
s.groupby(s).transform(lambda g: black_box(g.name).get())
```

This applies the function only once per group, but returns a series of the same shape as the caller.

---

**Edit**: timing comparisons (using Scott's example)

```
s = df['key']

%timeit s.groupby(s).transform(lambda g: factorial(g.name))
# 100 loops, best of 3: 3.92 ms per loop

%timeit df['result'] = df.key.map(dict)
# 100 loops, best of 3: 2.22 ms per loop
```

Comment: This looks good too yes, only issue I have is `groupby` operations tend to be the slowest in pandas, but besides that I think it's pretty good.

Comment: Scott's solution is twice as fast. I knew it would be faster, but I didn't want to steal his answer ;)